# Flask using dummy data in multiple routes NameError: name 'products' is not defined

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

Working on my first Flask app, an e-commerce site and I'm learning as I go along using dummy data.
I have a brands page (multiple brands displayed), an individual brand page (all products for brand), and a products page that shows 1 product rendering it's data from an array.

My code below has 3 routes -

`@app.route('/brands', methods=['GET','POST'])`,

`@app.route('/brands/<string:product_brand>', methods=['GET','POST'])`,

`@app.route('/brands/Brand1/<int:product_id>', methods=['GET','POST'])`

I have dummy data in the routes -

`@app.route('/brands', methods=['GET','POST'])`,

`@app.route('/brands/<string:product_brand>', methods=['GET','POST'])`,

---

`/brands` route has an array called brands which works and can pull data when rendering in HTML fine -

```
{% for brand in brandnames %}
{{ brand.name }}
```

This would render `Brand1` for the first loop

---

`/brands/<string:product_brand>/` has an array called products, the route uses a variable product_brand. If the variable is NOT part of the brands array(in the 1st route), a 404 error is thrown. Otherwise a coming soon page or the brand page is shown depending on the value of product_brand.
This works fine and can render in html -

```
{% for product in products %}
{{ product.name }}
```

This would render `example text` for the first loop

I can even set a link to go to the 3rd route by setting the href to -

```
{{ url_for('product', product_id = product.product_id ) }}
```

This renders as the link's endpoint as `/brands/Brand1/1` which is correct and should show the product page for the product with id 1.

---

However when I try to set up the 3rd route as I have done the second and first; I can't seem to read data from the previous route's arrays (Brands & Products arrays).
I don't know how I managed to pass data from brands array into the second route (`if product_brand not in brands`) but can't do (`if product_id not in products`)

Whenever i click a link  that leads to, or manually go to the URL (e.g. `/brands/Brand1/1`) I get a `NameError: name 'products' is not defined` error.

Part of my routes code is below:

```
@app.route('/brands', methods=['GET','POST'])
def brands():
    brands = [
        {
            'name': 'Brand1',
            'image': 'B1.jpg'
        },
        {
            'name': 'Brand2',
            'image': 'B2.jpg'
        },
        {
            'name': 'Brand3',
            'image': 'B3.jpg'
        }
        {
            'name': 'Sale',
            'image': 'S1.jpg'
        }
    ]
    
    return render_template('brands.html', title='Brands', brandnames=brands)

@app.route('/brands/<string:product_brand>', methods=['GET','POST'])
def productbrand(product_brand):
    
    products = [
        {
            'brand': 'Brand1',
            'name': 'example text',
            'thumbname': 'e.g.text',
            'cart_thumb': 'small.jpg',
            'product_id': '1',
            'price': '100',
            'sale':'Yes',
            'product_large_1': 'L1.jpg',
            'product_large_2': 'L2.jpg',
            'product_large_3': 'L3.jpg',
            'product_thumb_1': 'T1.jpg',
            'product_thumb_2': 'T2.jpg',
            'product_thumb_3': 'T3.jpg'
        },
        {
            'brand': 'Brand2',
            'name': 'example text',
            'thumbname': 'e.g.text',
            'cart_thumb': 'small.jpg',
            'product_id': '2',
            'price': '200',
            'sale':'Yes',
            'product_large_1': 'L1.jpg',
            'product_large_2': 'L2.jpg',
            'product_large_3': 'L3.jpg',
            'product_thumb_1': 'T1.jpg',
            'product_thumb_2': 'T2.jpg',
            'product_thumb_3': 'T3.jpg'
        },
        {
            'brand': 'Brand1',
            'name': 'example text',
            'thumbname': 'e.g.text',
            'cart_thumb': 'small.jpg',
            'product_id': '3',
            'price': '100',
            'sale':'No',
            'product_large_1': 'L1.jpg',
            'product_large_2': 'L2.jpg',
            'product_large_3': 'L3.jpg',
            'product_thumb_1': 'T1.jpg',
            'product_thumb_2': 'T2.jpg',
            'product_thumb_3': 'T3.jpg'
        }
    ]

    if product_brand not in brands():
        abort(404)
    elif product_brand not in ['Brand1', 'Sale']:
        return render_template('comingsoon.html', product_brand=product_brand)
    else:
        return render_template('brandpage.html', product_brand=product_brand, products=products)
   



@app.route('/brands/Brand1/<int:product_id>', methods=['GET','POST'])
def product(product_id):
    
    return render_template('product.html', title='Product', products=products, product_id=product_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

`products` id defined under `productbrand` but you try to use it from `product` as well. Moving `products` to the global scope will solve it.